# Can I use Scala 3 export in extension of opaque type to expose the inner type methods selectively?

Tags: scala, delegates, export, scala-3, opaque-types

I would like to have exports working with opaque tyeps in Scala 3:

```
opaque type BigNumber = BigInt

object BigNumber:
  def apply(s: String): BigNumber = BigInt(s)

  extension (cv: BigNumber) 
    export cv.(unary_- as myUnary}

val c = BigNumber("7")

c.myUnary  // I wish to have -7 as BigNumber
```

It would be very handy to work that way.
But it doesn't work :/

What is the walkaround?

Answer (score 0):

[Michał Pałka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22439955/prolativ) has shown me this working hack:

```
object OpaqueScope:
  opaque type BigNumber = BigInt

  object BigNumber:
    def apply(s: String): BigNumber = BigInt(s)

    extension (cv: BigNumber)
      def value: BigInt = cv
      export value.{unary_- as myUnary}

import OpaqueScope.BigNumber
val c = BigNumber("7")

c.myUnary // returns -7 as BigInt
```

It's even in the official [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/export.html#export-clauses-in-extensions).

**DRAWBACK**: type is not preserved :(

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the return type `BigNumber` you can't use `export` as for 2023:

```
object OpaqueScope:
  opaque type BigNumber = BigInt

  object BigNumber:
    def apply(s: String): BigNumber = BigInt(s)

    extension (cv: BigNumber)
      def myUnary: BigNumber = cv.unary_-

import OpaqueScope.BigNumber
val c = BigNumber("7")

c.myUnary // returns -7 as BigNumber
```